# Autoscaling does not properly create instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

I am getting this error when I am trying to fire up instances using autoscaling policies and groups.

```
Cancelled: Launching a new EC2 instance: i-50dd31cc. Status Reason: Only EC2-Classic instances may be linked.
```

I am using the following commands to create autoscaling launch configuration and autoscaling group.

```
aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name my-lc --image-id ami-12345678 --instance-type c4.large --classic-link-vpc-id vpc-1345622 --user-data file:///Users/path/Desktop/myscript.sh --classic-link-vpc-security-groups sg-sad34353 --spot-price "0.5"

aws autoscaling create-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name my-asg --launch-configuration-name my-lc --availability-zones "us-east-1a" "us-east-1e" --max-size 10 --min-size 1 --desired-capacity 10 --vpc-zone-identifier 'subnet-asd3r322,subnet-asdasd12'
```

And then I am creating Cloudwatch alarms based on the number of messages in the SQS. Everything seems fine and the instances run correctly. But the problem is that they are always in the "pending" state. And then after exactly half an hour, they get shut down with the above mentioned error.

How do I link only classic EC2-instances?

Also I have one more problem that is related to the "desired" instances. My min count is 1, max is 10 and desired is 10. So when I start the group and there are no messages in the SQS, then the desired capacity automatically goes down to 1. But when there are 1000 messages even for more than half an hour, there is no increase in desired capacity. Still only one instance is running. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 questions here, so I'll try to answer them both as best I can.

Launch Configuration: It appears you are trying to create a launch configuration to launch instances into EC2 Classic linked to a VPC. What you have defined in your launch configuration is to launch a c4.large (VPC only type instance) with classic-link enabled to a VPC. You would need to select an instance type compatible with EC2 Classic.

AutoScaling Group: You are attempting to launch an instance from the launch configuration with classic-link enabled (implying you want to launch it into EC2 Classic, but you are supplying a VPC (subnet-id) to launch it in. You should not be supplying the VPC subnet id's to launch it in.

The commands individually are not incorrect, so you are not receiving any errors, but they are not compatible to be used together at launch time.

CloudWatch: I suggest solving the first problem, and asking a separate question about your CloudWatch alarms not working, but I suspect you don't have the alarm linked to the autoscaling group. See this url for more info on that: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html

Comment: So if I launch "c3" instead of "c4", and if I do not provide the subnet-id, would it be a step in the right direction?

Comment: Well, before you answer, I used "c3.large" instead of "c4.large" and did not provide the subnet-id: IT WORKED. Instances are successfully created. But what if I want to use "c4.large" instances. How will I use them?

Comment: You can't use c4 instances in EC2 Classic: [see the limitations in the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/c4-instances.html#c4-instance-limit). If you want to use c4, you need to migrate those instances directly into the VPC and not use classic-link. Which I recommend doing anyway as any new instances types coming out in the future will not be available to EC2 Classic. Amazon is trying to move people away from using EC2 Classic, in fact new accounts created today don't even have access to EC2 Classic, only VPC.

Comment: How do I migrate? Is there any tutorial for that? using Amazon CLI.

Comment: [This section of the documentation may help](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate.html).  It depends on how complex your environment is, it could be as simple as re-launching all of your EC2 instances into a VPC. The link covers incremental migration using classic-link, I would suggest avoiding that if possible. It has some issues as you've already experienced.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I just had to remove the "classic link vpc" and "classic link security groups" for using c4.large. Now everything is working perfectly!